# Integration AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers Steam authorization with reactive.js?

Tags: aspnet-contrib

I have a ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web API which uses Steam login for authentication using [this](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenId.Providers) package. 
My authentication looks like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
      .AddCookie(options =>
      {
          options.LoginPath = "/Api/Login";
          options.LogoutPath = "/Api/Logout";
      })
      .AddSteam(opt => { opt.CallbackPath = "/Home/SteamCallback"; opt.ApplicationKey = "XXXX"; });
```

I'm using this API with my react app and I want to login so I added this in my react project to login

```
<a href="https://localhost:44390/api/login">Via Steam</a>
```

And /api/login redirects user back to react's homepage:

```
[HttpGet("/api/login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string provider="Steam")
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "http://localhost:3000/" }, provider);
    }
```

I know it's so stupid to try authorize like that but i dont have any idea how.
Also they say using JWT is not safe in here so I had to use cookies but could not handle how to pass logged data to react and fetch data successfully.